# Ubuntu 12.10 - Graphics driver shows Gallium 0.4 instead of intel HD

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10, intel, hybrid

I have a hybrid Intel/Nvidia system using bumblebee on Ubuntu 12.10 with specs:
Clevo W150HR, SB i7-2720qm, 8GB RAM, 128GB Crucial M4 SSD + 500GB HDD
It is reported to use software rendering (through Gallium driver) rather than accelerated through the intel HD driver.
Reinstalling the intel driver has no effect:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

The result is a rather sluggish desktop. Is there any way to blacklist the gallium driver?  Or force the intel driver instead?

**Edit 1** - Ubuntu 12.04 shows the driver as Intel SandyBridge out of the box, but 12.10 does not even after running the above command.

**Edit 2** - Xorg.0.log shows:

> (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile (GT1)
>   (WW) intel(0): Disabling hardware acceleration on this pre-production hardware.

**Edit 3** - It turns out that SandyBridge rev.7 systems are known to be unstable [per this link](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31773). Accordingly in the [xserver-xorg-video-intel](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-intel/commit/?id=1ee10cc3b2aa0888753eeb25c7fde7296a3c92eb) if it detects this rev. it disables it with the warning in above log.

Comment: Bumblebee is only for the nvidia driver as far as I know. I read that you can use bumblebee to run unity. But can't recall where. I have the same issue, the VMware Gallium driver is used. However this just happend after using alx driver for the ethernet card. Before that, the correct driver from Intel was used for the intel vga card. So, I guess, we'r looking for a solution on how to force Intel's VGA driver.

Comment: I only added the bumblebee comment to emphasize i am using a hybrid system. Bumblebee itself is irrelevant i think in this issue as 12.10 out of the box shows the Gallium driver instead of the intel driver.

Comment: Can't we just modprobe the right driver? I'm looking for the correct name of the inteldriver to use it with modprobe.

Comment: Xorg.0.log shows the following entry: (WW) intel(0): Disabling hardware acceleration on this pre-production hardware.

Comment: Currently fubarred my kernel with trying to fix it. Re-installing ubuntu or compiling new kernel over the weekend. We'll see what driver is used then.

Comment: @Redlab: Apparantly i am running a rev7 chipset which is unstable and therefore disabled. I have the original 2630qm still lying around somewhere, i will check if that doesnt show this error. You should check which revision you are using.

Comment: I just installed 12.10 again and it works again. Apparently I had broken modules due to using linux-backports-modules-cw-.... for my wired network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a preferred solution but i was able to bypass the issue by swapping my 2720qm with my original 2630qm. Graphics are now accelerated by the intel hd drivers. The problem is with the 2720qm which apparantly is unstable (see edit 3 above)

Comment: Nvidia & Linux, it has never been the best combination. At least now your slugginess is gone!